# call function of class on instance of class

Tags: function, class, oop, unity-game-engine

I have some code that generates answers based on the user input. But in somecases i need to update the values later by calling `SetAnswers` But when i compile my code i get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I get this error on the line marked by the arrow.
See below for my code:

```
public class Generate_Questions : MonoBehaviour{

public Question q5, q4;


void Start(){

    q4 = create_question("Select object to edit", EXTERNAL);
    Visual_Question vq1 = new Visual_Question(1, q4, new vector(1,1,1), Ui, Canvas);
    vq1.draw_question();
}

void Update(){

}




   public class Visual_Question : Generate_Questions{

        public Visual_Question(int order_id, Question q, Vector2 loc, Dictionary<string, RectTransform> ui, RectTransform canvas){
        }

        public void draw_question(){
            q4.SetAnswers(new Answer[]{ <--------- this generates the error. 
                new Answer(null, "Select an option")
            });
        }
    }


    public class Question{

        public string text;
        public int answers_loc;
        public List<Answer> answers;

        public Question(string q_text, int answers_loc){
            answers = new List<Answer>();
            this.text = q_text;
            this.answers_loc = answers_loc;
        }

        public void SetAnswers(Answer[] c_answers){
            foreach(Answer answer in c_answers){
                this.answers.Add(answer);
            }
        }

        public bool CheckIfAnswersAvailable(){
            if(answers.Count > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public int QuestionLocation(){
            return answers_loc;
        }
    }

    public Question create_question(string text, int a_type){
        Question Q = new Question(text, a_type);
        return Q;
    }

    public interface IAnswer{
        string GetText();
        string GetDataType();
        object GetValue();
        Question GetNextQuestion();
    }

    public class Answer : IAnswer{

        public string text;
        public Question next = null;
        public int? action = null;
        public Element obj = null;
        public string property = null;
        public float? value = null;

        public Answer(Question next, string text){
            this.text = text;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public Answer(Question next, string text, Element obj, int? action){
            this.action = action;
            this.text = text;
            this.next = next;
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        public Answer(Question next, string text, Element obj, int? action, string property, float? value){
            this.action = action;
            this.next = next;
            this.text = text;
            this.obj = obj;
            this.property = property;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public string GetText(){
            return text;
        }

        public string GetDataType(){
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetValue(){
            return value;
        }

        public Question GetNextQuestion(){
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

how would i go about fixing this problem? I am a complete newbie to c#. So my question may be already answered but i just dont know what i am looking for.

Comment: Post your IAnswer and Answer classes please

Comment: added the classes and interfaces

Comment: seems like @Ivan Kaloyanov was right, your IAnswer is an interface, so you have to restructure it :(

Comment: Your SetAnswers() method expects object which implements IAnswer so in your case you have to pass objects of class Answer which implements IAnswer and to  create new constructor with two params if you want to create it like that "new Answer(null, "Select an option")" p.s. I strongly suggest you to spend some time on OOP it will be very useful for you :)

Comment: Flagged as duplicate then re-opened after realizing it was one more than just one issue. If your script inherits from MonoBehaviour then don't derive from that script. MonoBehaviour  don't work well with inheritance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `IAnswer[]` is an interface and since you are trying to initialize an abstract object you get that runtime exception

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

if you want to create instance of `IAnswer` object you have to restructure it like class or structure.

Comment: ok i am not sure exactly what you mean. Could you maybe give an example in code. That would really help!

Comment: Sure :) Can you share your IAnswer.cs file ?

Comment: I added the IAnswer interface and Answer class

Comment: ok gonna try that. Hopefully my program wil still work afterwards

Comment: I replaced the IAnswer with Answer. But i still have the same error. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Visual_Question derives from Generate_Questions, so the member **q4** that you use en draw_question is not initialized. This is not the member of Generated_Questions but a member of Visual_Question that is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In `Generate_Questions` you are creating a new instance of `Visual_Question` and then immediately calling `draw_question` on that new instance. You now have 2 *instances* of a question (both derive from `Generate_Questions`), but only one of them has had the `Start` method, which initializes `q4` called. If, however, you attempt to call `Start` from your second instance, you're going to find yourself in an infinite series of recursive calls and quickly crash with a different error (a stack overflow in this case).

One issue with the current code is that `Generate_Questions` sounds more like an action than a class. I'd suggest removing the inheritance from `Visual_Question` and make that an interface that you would implement on `Question`. `Question` should probably have the `create_question` method removed. That probably belongs in a `MonoBehavior` script (technically it's a factory method -- look up the factory pattern -- I'm not going to go into it here since this is a beginner topic).

Something like (obviously not complete):

```cs
public class Generate_Questions : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IVisualQuestion q4;

    void Start() 
    {
        q4 = new Question("Select object to edit", EXTERNAL);
        q4.DrawQuestion(new vector(1,1,1), Ui, Canvas)
    }

    void Update() {}
}

public interface IVisualQuestion
{
    void DrawQuestion(Vector2 loc, Dictionary<string, RectTransform> ui, RectTransform canvas);
}

public class Question : IVisualQuestion
{
    // ... insert the Question constructor and code here ...

    // Implement VisualQuestion interface
    public void DrawQuestion(Vector2 loc, Dictionary<string, RectTransform> ui, RectTransform canvas)
    {
        this.SetAnswers(new Answer[]{new Answer(null, "Select an option")});
    }
}
```

In general, you probably don't need inheritance. As you learn more C#, you'll discover that when inheritance is going to help it will be clear. More often than not, using an interface is a far better and flexible approach. As a commenter noted, you probably don't want to inherit from `MonoBehavior`. You really only need that for classes that the Unity Engine is going to directly handle.

Another note: the convention in C# is to name methods, variables, etc. in PascalCase, not using underscores to separate words.